# Is there a way to get a file that's dropped onto the application icon on Mac and Windows?

Tags: actionscript-3, air

On Mac it's possible to drop a file onto the application icon in the application dock. Is it possible to get that information and is it possible to do the same on Windows?

I've been reading up on the [InvokeEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a5d46-8000.html) but I haven't seen it say it's possible to get a file dropped on it's icon. It also doesn't say if that feature is supported on Windows.

**Bonus points:**
How to test this since Flash Builder the application is not installed (launches through debug).

Comment: Imagine the person who could answer you about Windows does not have a Mac. What happens when you do this drop? Is it similar to the **"Open With..."** option in Windows? What do you mean by "...get a file..." exactly, like if I drag a "picture.jpg" file onto Photoshop icon then what does the AIR app have to do with it or want to get in this example?

Comment: yes. just like that. it is same as open with on Windows and it is the same as drag an image onto Photoshop. I want to get the file reference or path to image. but it is mostly for dragging and dropping into app icon.

Comment: You need to register the file type your app can open and then listen it in invoke event

Comment: thank you that solves the "open with" problem. one problem solved. I'm still searching to find how to know how to solve drag and drop on application icon.

Comment: I think just handling the invoke event and checking for arguments and standard invoke method might do it. have to test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got it work on Mac and should work on Windows.

When you register for different file types then you can drop files on the icon and the application opens and an invoke event is dispatched after you add an event listener for it (problem 1 solved). Registering file types also allows you to use "Open with..." on both Mac and Windows (problem 2 solved).

If you are using Flash Builder or another IDE to test if your invoke function works you can add a path to the file in your Run/Debug launch arguments (bonus points). Put quotes around it and separate it by a space to add additional arguments.

[image]

You have to add an event listener to the application and then after that any and all invokes will be dispatched. Until then they are only queued.

When you drop multiple files onto the application icon on Mac there will be a single invoke event with multiple arguments. On Windows and Linux this event will be dispatched multiple times with a single argument. Each argument is the full path to the file.

If you open an application normally and listen for the invoke event it is dispatched even if no files were dropped on the application. This is a standard invoke type and contains no arguments.

The example below listens for the invoke event and handles different cases.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 

                       invoke="windowedapplication1_invokeHandler(event)"
                       >

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[

            protected function windowedapplication1_invokeHandler(event:InvokeEvent):void {
                var invokeArguments:Array = event.arguments;
                var filePath:String;
                var stream:FileStream;
                var file:File;
                var testing:Boolean = false;


                // application icon had a file dropped on it or an associated file was double clicked while app was open
                if (event.reason == InvokeEventReason.STANDARD && invokeArguments.length) {

                    invokeWithFile(event.currentDirectory, invokeArguments);
                }


                // application opened normally
                if (event.reason == InvokeEventReason.STANDARD && 
                    (invokeArguments.length == 0 || testing)) {

                    if (testing) {
                        invokeArguments = ["/Users/me/Desktop/test.jpg"];
                    }

                    invokeWithFile(event.currentDirectory, invokeArguments);

                    return;
                }

                // application opened at login
                if (event.reason == InvokeEventReason.LOGIN) {
                    return;
                }

                // application opened from URL
                if (event.reason == InvokeEventReason.OPEN_URL) {
                    return;
                }

                // application opened from notification such as iOS APN
                if (event.reason == InvokeEventReason.NOTIFICATION) {
                    return;
                }
            }

            public var invokedFile:File;

            /**
             * Invoked file. 
             * */
            public function invokeWithFile(currentDirectory:File, invokedArguments:Array):void {
                var filePath:String = invokedArguments && invokedArguments.length ? invokedArguments[0] : null;
                var fileData:String;
                var fileStream:FileStream;
                var file:File;

                if (filePath) {
                    try {
                        file = new File(filePath);
                    }
                    catch (errorEvent:*) {
                        trace("Error: " + errorEvent.toString());
                        return;
                    }

                    if (file && 
                        file.exists && 
                        file.isDirectory==false && 
                        file.extension && 
                        file.extension.toLowerCase()=="mxml") {
                        fileStream = new FileStream();

                        try {
                            fileStream.open(file, FileMode.READ);

                            if (fileStream.bytesAvailable) {
                                fileData = fileStream.readUTFBytes(fileStream.bytesAvailable);
                            }
                        }
                        catch (error:*) {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

</s:WindowedApplication>
```

Here is the application descriptor file. File types are strict. I've included notes inline:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/20.0">

    <fileTypes>

        <fileType>
            <!--  name cannot contain a space -->
            <name>MXML.File</name>
            <!--  extension cannot be * -->
            <extension>mxml</extension>
            <description>MXML file</description>
            <!--  content type is required -->
            <contentType>text/plain</contentType>
        </fileType>
        <fileType>
            <name>Photoshop.Image</name>
            <extension>psd</extension>
            <description>Adobe Photoshop Image</description>
            <contentType>application/octet-stream</contentType>
        </fileType>
        <fileType>
            <name>JPEG.Image</name>
            <extension>jpg</extension>
            <description>JPEG Image</description>
            <contentType>image/jpeg</contentType>
        </fileType>
        <fileType>
            <name>JPEG.Image</name>
            <extension>jpeg</extension>
            <description>JPEG Image</description>
            <contentType>image/jpeg</contentType>
        </fileType>
        <fileType>
            <name>PNG.Image</name>
            <extension>png</extension>
            <description>PNG Image</description>
            <contentType>image/png</contentType>
        </fileType>
        <fileType>
            <name>GIF.Image</name>
            <extension>gif</extension>
            <description>GIF Image</description>
            <contentType>image/gif</contentType>
        </fileType>

    </fileTypes>

</application>
```

**File type errors:**

Error 104: application.fileTypes.fileType.contentType is required. 
Solution: You must include the content type. Other places online mentioned it was optional but it may now be required. 
[image: ContentType is required error]

Error 104: application.fileTypes.fileType.extension is required. 
Solution: You must include the extension.
[image]

Error 105: application.fileTypes.fileType.extension contains an invalid value. 
Solution: Extension cannot be empty or *.
[image]

Error 105: application.fileTypes.fileType.name contains an invalid value. 
Solution: The name cannot contain a space character. 
[image]